# In Mapbox.js, how to switch between different map style?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, mapbox

In this page

https://www.mapbox.com/editor/#style

Different map styles can be switched easily by clicking on style thumbnails. I tried to check the source code of that page as well as Mapbox API but still have no ideas about how they implement that..

Does anyone have ideas about which method is used to switch between different map styles in mapbox.js?

Comment: They're toggling the layers (removing + adding). I think this example may help: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/layers/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be clear, switching 'map styles' with raster tilelayers means loading entirely new tile layers.  What you are looking at on MapBox's browser editor are 15 different possible tilelayers, (with only one rendered at a time).  So, creating a new style means creating an entirely new project (i.e., depending on how you implement it, a new `.mbtiles` file, or a new project on your tileserver).

So, to answer your question, new tile layers can be added/removed from a map using the `map.removeLayer()` and `map.addLayer()` methods ([see the docs](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.1.5/l-map-class/#map-stuff-methods)).

Browser-based rendering, with styles applied by the client, rather than being hard baked into the tileset, is possible with vector-tiles and the [mapbox-gl](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl/) library, though `mapbox-gl` is not yet as mature as `leaflet`/`mapbox.js`.

Answer (score 0):

I use something like next piece of code to change map styles. This code switches current map style and removes old map after loading first tile of new map style.

```js
L.Map.include({
    _mapStyleLayerTileLoad:function(){
        this._stylesLayer.getLayers()
            .filter(function(layer){
                return this._currentStyleLayer!==layer;
            },this)
            .forEach(function(layer){
                if (layer!==this._currentStyleLayer) {
                    this._stylesLayer.removeLayer(layer);
                }
            },this);
        this._currentStyleLayer.off("tileload",this._mapStyleLayerTileLoad,this);
    },
    setMapStyle:function(style) {
        if (!style) {
            return;
        }
        if (!this._stylesLayer) {
            this._stylesLayer=L.layerGroup([]).addTo(this);
        }
        if (this._currentStyleLayer) {
            this._currentStyleLayer.off("tileload",this._mapStyleTileLoad);
        }
        var layer=L.mapbox.tileLayer(style)
        if (this._currentStyleLayer) {
            layer.on("tileload",this._mapStyleLayerTileLoad,this);
        }
        layer.addTo(this._stylesLayer);
        this._currentStyleLayer=layer;
        return this;
    }
});
```